# using PDO instead of mysql_*

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have changed the following code:

```
mysql_connect('localhost','username','password');
mysql_select_db('pl') or die( "Unable to select database");
```

to

```
PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pl;charset=UTF-8', 'username', 'password');
```

Is it correct or do I have to pass this to a variable (in the PDO tutorial it is being passed to a variable db; what is the purpose of that? http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)

Comment: You obviously need to be able to access the database connection you just opened...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Modify your code from:

```
PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pl;charset=UTF-8', 'username', 'password');
```

To:

```
$Connection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pl;charset=UTF-8', 'username', 'password');
```

and your basic query structure will revolve around your `$Connection` variable. Example:

```
$Query = $Connection->query("LIST TABLES");
$Results = $Query->fetchAll();
```

which is kind of like:

```
$Query = mysql_query("LIST TABLES");
$Results = mysql_fetch_array($Query);
```

Read these manuals:

[Construct A connection (Like mysql_connect/mysql_select_db)](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php%20s)

[PDO Query (Like mysql_query();](http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.query.php%20fr)

[Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php%20Prepared%20Statements)

[Execute Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)

[PDO FetchAll (like mysql_fetch_array)](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

[Entire PDO Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: What is the replacement for mysql_real_escape_string in PDO?

Comment: Use prepared statements instead. `mysql_real_escape_string` and similar techniques are messy and don't deal with all injections.

Comment: @user1925118 -- Kitsune is correct with using Prepared statements; but there is also a range of binds available with the PDO API, which give you enhanced Protection

Answer (score 1):

This is better, as it can catch exception if something goes wrong (so, I have been told)

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb', 'root', 'test', array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

obviously, you need to change the mydb, root and test.

Now, the only thing that remains is to call `$conn` when ever your  do you queries.

*Remember,* **catching an exception** is a bit like the `or die(mysql_error());` part of sql connection. But, this one will do it in a way, any error will not show your entire file location, which could be  a security threat.

Additionally, I would suggest you take a look at these tutorials to lean more:

1. [PHP Database Access: Are You Doing It Correctly?](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly/)
2. [PDO Tutorial for MySQL Developers](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)

Comment: -1: exceptions have nothing in common with `die()/exit`